# angular ui.router ui-sref replace url characters - beautify

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I'm searching for a possibility to replace characters in the ui-sref, respecting the URL of a target.

```
.state('base.product.detail', {
    url: 'detail/:productName-:productId/'
```

The URLs now look like:

```
Now: 
http://localhost/detail/My%20Product%20Name-123456789/

Should:
http://localhost/detail/My-Product-Name-123456789/
```

I want to get rid of the %20 (which are also directly generated inside ui-sref="") and replace them with a minus (-).

Any ideas how to do that?

Regards, Markus

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Register a custom type that marshalls and unmarshalls the data.  Docs here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$urlMatcherFactory

Let's define a custom type. Implement encode, decode, is and pattern:

```
  var productType = {
    encode: function(str) { return str && str.replace(/ /g, "-"); },
    decode: function(str) { return str && str.replace(/-/g, " "); },
    is: angular.isString,
    pattern: /[^/]+/
  };
```

Now register the custom type as 'product' with `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider`:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {
  $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('product', productType);
}
```

Now define your url parameter as a product and the custom type will do the mapping for you:

```
  $stateProvider.state('baseproductdetail', {
    url: '/detail/{productName:product}-:productId/',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) { 
      $scope.product = $stateParams.productName;
      $scope.productId = $stateParams.productId;
    },
    template: "<h3>name: {{product}}</h3><h3>name: {{productId}}</h3>"
  });
```

Working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/wsiu7cx5rfZLawzyjHtf?p=preview

Comment: Is it possible to use custom types so curly brackets( { ) not apper as '%7B' in the URL? Reference to this question I have made http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204064/angular-ui-router-curly-brackets-etc-in-url

Comment: How to replace spaces with plus sign (+)? I've tried changing "-" with "+" but it's not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Very easy approach:

In the controller, where the ui-sref is used (or even better in a separate service):

```
$scope.beautyEncode = function(string){
    string = string.replace(/ /g, '-');
    return string;
};
```

In the template:

```
<a href="" ui-sref="base.product.detail({productName: beautyEncode(product.name), productId: product.id})">
```

The routing itself wasn't changed, angular did the routing still correctly.

Comment: Yup this is the quickest and the easiest. It should be the accepted answer.