# how to stop ui-sref encoding url params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Here is the link I'm using with `ui-sref` attribute directive:

```
<a ui-ref="show.hastitle({uuid:item.uuid, title:item.title})">
```

Title parameter can be a Persian word, and what I expect is such as link below:

`http://domain.com/page/54c82de2978af/واژه-فارسی`

but `ui-sref` returns like below:

`http://domain.com/page/54c82de2978af/%D9%88%D8%A7%DA%98%D9%87-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C`

I've used such solutions as below:

```
var noneEncodedUri = {
      encode: function(str) { return str && str.replace(/ /g, "-"); },
      decode: function(str) { return str && str.replace(/-/g, " "); },
      is: angular.isString,
      pattern: /[^/]+/
};

$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('noneEncodedUri', noneEncodedUri);

$stateProvider.state('mystate', {
      url: "/{title:noneEncodedUri}"
 })
```

But the rendered link didn't change
how can I stop `ui-sref` encoding url params completely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular ui.router ui-sref replace url characters - beautify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918231/angular-ui-router-ui-sref-replace-url-characters-beautify)

Answer (score 2):

I've used this scope function to solve my issue:

```
$scope.beautyUri = function (uuid, title) {
    return decodeURIComponent($state.href("show.hastitle", {uuid: uuid, title: title}));
  };
```

and use this function in html like this:

```
<a href="{{beautyUri(item.uuid, item.title)}}">{{title}}</a>
```

Comment: it's better to use `ng-href`

Answer (score 0):

i hade this problem to but after a lot of unsuccessful searches , find the solution it's very simple actually
you can use javaScript `decodeURIComponent()` function on `$scope.item.title` for me it's worked like charm .