# Angular ui-router - Curly brackets etc in url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I have been searching for a way to have curly brackets`{}` and slashes `/` in the URL. But the URL looks like this:

```
URL appearance now:
http://localhost/#/?ph=tes:testes%2Ftest%7Blb0%7D

URL wanted appearance:
http://localhost/#/?ph=tes:tests/test{lb0}
```

How do I get an URL without the %2f etc?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think we support "raw" parameters in upcoming ui-router 1.0

Comment: Okey, do you have any estimate when ui-router 1.0 will be out? And for now, do you have any recommendation for my problem or is it just waiting for 1.0? Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1):

All *valid* characters that can be used in a URI (a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) is a type of [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)) are defined in [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

All other characters can be used in a URL provided that they are "URL Encoded" first.  This involves changing the invalid character for specific "codes" (usually in the form of the percent symbol (%) followed by a hexadecimal number).

This link, [HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), contains a list of the encodings for invalid characters.

Happy Helping!

Answer (score 0):

These (%2F, %7B) are escape sequences. They represent the special characters that are in your URL, as a URL cannot contain these character directly.

Where do you want exactly to process this URL?

You can use Javascript's `unescape(url)` to get the escaped URL string back to the original one if you're going to process it in Javascript itself.